# Switch Case Considered as a Duplicate Label with JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION

Tags: java, switch-statement, joptionpane

I am currently using IntelliJ and an error that says "Duplicate label '2'" appears when I am placing a case for pressing the CANCEL option in my menu.

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args){
      int choice=0;
         Object menu= "1. Name Constructor\n" +
                 "2. Pretty Printing of text\n" +
                 "3. FLAMES\n" +
                 "4. Your Superhero name!\n" +
                 "5. return to the main menu\n";
      do {
        choice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "S T R I N G  M A N I P U L A T I O N  M E N U\n" +
      menu, "Menu", 1));
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            case JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION:
                break;
            default:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter a valid  choice.","Error",1);
                break;
          }
       }while(choice!=5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening because you can't define two cases with the same value in the switch statement.

If you take a look inside the JOptionPane, you'll see that the `CANCEL_OPTION` value is 2.

Here is the part of the JOptionPane class that shows the value:

`/** Return value from class method if CANCEL is chosen. */
    public static final int CANCEL_OPTION = 2;`

As you already have a `case 2:` and the `CANCEL_OPTION` also returns 2, you have to change it. For example, if you change to `case 6:` it will work. Give it a try.

[here](https://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cdc/opt-pkgs/api/agui/jsr209/constant-values.html#javax.swing.JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) you can see all the values that a JOptionPane has, so you can modify your case according to other values, so you don't get this duplicate case error anymore.